# How do I compute the DNS server response time?

Tags: networking, dns

If I send a request from my computer to the local DNS server, how long should I wait for a response from it?

I probably need to consider the propagation delay, transition delay...what else?

Comment: You should wait a few seconds. Just try it and you'll get a feel for how fast it responds and how much deviation there is in the response times.

Answer (score 0):

It should be within a second, including the connection establishment, network latency, and processing at the DNS server.

If you are querying a recursive DNS server, then be aware that the response time will differ based on the state of that server's cache. If you query something that is already with the server, response will be faster. Try querying a non existent domain to factor in the recursion time as well.